# Change default travel type maps

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

I have an iPhone running iOS 12. Is there anyway to change the travel type as I walk a lot so that it automatically gets walking directions where possible and shows travel times as walking times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be changed in Settings -> Maps -> Preferred Transport Type.

[image]

Change it to walking or your choice of transport.

When you set your mode of transport it will automatically give directions for that transport type:

[image]

The type can still be changed manually if you are using another mode of transport but it will be set to your choice by default.